# How do I merge two CSV files on common index values in Python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I have two CSV files, **CSV_Cleaned**: It has *891* rows and  **CSV_Uncleaned**: this one has *945* rows, I wish to get only those rows from **CSV_Uncleaned** whose index value matches with **CSV_Cleaned**. How do I do it?

NOTE: My data frame has no column named 'index', I am talking about the index values that are automatically generated on the left of the 1st column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the column of interest is called `"index"` on the csv files, you can do this using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('CSV_cleaned.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('CSV_Uncleaned.csv')
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='index', right_on='index', how='left')
```

in case you already have `DataFrame`s that need to be merged by their index:

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

Comment: No , i am talking about the index column that pandas generates anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mateo.You fixed my problem.I wish you have a great time ahead PS-Sorry for delayed reply

Comment: @AbhinavPipil If the answer fixed your problem, please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Sorry It slipped my mind, have accepted your answer now :)